# Multi expand foundation accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I had implement in my code a foundation accordion.

When I click on a tab, the already opened tab collapse and the new tab is set to active.

My goal is to have the possibility to open more tab at the same time, and close them only by clicking on them.

Searching on the foundation documentation I have found this: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html

But I can't make work the multi_expand option, and I don't understand why.

My foundation.accordion.js version is the 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try making separate acordions http://jsfiddle.net/9kq0ar5v/

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <dd class="accordion-navigation">
    <a href="#panel1">Accordion 1</a>
    <div id="panel1" class="content">
      ladida
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <dd class="accordion-navigation">
    <a href="#panel2">Accordion 2</a>
    <div id="panel2" class="content">
       lalalaa
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to set the "multi_expand" flag? I was able to get this working using the following code at the end of my page.

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation('accordion', { multi_expand: true });
</script>
```

You may need to upgrade to a newer version of foundation for this to work. It worked in 5.4.1.